# Renderscript samples build errors

Tags: android, build, renderscript

So I wanted to try out the samples that use RenderScript, and I imported HelloWorld in Eclipse. But it gives me errors like:

```
[2011-10-25 13:10:48 - HelloWorld] /home/mileoresko/workspace/utils/android-sdk-linux_86
/platforms/android-11/renderscript/include/rs_graphics.rsh:240:58: error: unknown type 
name 'float3'; did you mean 'float'?
[2011-10-25 13:10:48 - HelloWorld] /home/mileoresko/workspace/utils/android-sdk-linux_86 
/platforms/android-11/renderscript/include/rs_graphics.rsh:237:31: error: unknown type 
name 'rs_mesh'
```

Also i noticed that the files that need to generate in the gen folder are missing?? (classes like ScriptC_helloworld).
I've searched all morning for a solution but I was not able to find one. I updated the SDK and the ADT,  don't know what could be the problem. Please if someone had this problem and found/knows a solution, share it with me, am I desperate. I can not build any project from the samples. Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug in the tools. It will be fixed, but there is a workaround:

Replace /platforms/android-[11|12|13]/renderscript with the version located at /platforms/android-14/renderscript

This will copy the newest headers into older platforms and make your project compile.

Here's the bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21006

Comment: I downloaded the SDK's through Eclipse and don't have /renderscript in my /android-14 dir. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like these files were moved to platform-tools/renderscript

Comment: @robertly i trying hello compute on android api 4.2. Even then the script files are not generated automatically.