# Setting up Renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I've decided to start learning Renderscript as a possible solution to my next project.  However, I'm having trouble even getting Eclipse to run the thing.  I'm importing the examples that come with the SDK 11.  It seems to have trouble importing the headers.  Eclipse doesn't recognize the directives like `pragma` or `extern`.  Also, whenever I include a required file such as `rs_core.h` a message pops up stating `llvm-rs-cc.exe has stopped working`.  I assume there's some sort of setup that I'm missing, but I can't find anywhere on the web that explains it.

Comment: There was an issue with one of the versions of ADT and the RenderScript headers.  I'd first verify that you have the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Replace /platforms/android-[11|12|13]/renderscript with the version located at /platforms/android-14/renderscript" see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889689/renderscript-samples-build-errors).

Comment: @Ian G. Clifton I am not haveing rederscript folder inside my platform/android-[>=14], and I tried to add them manually, but issues is still there